# Which is the right variant for "bind" or "tie-in" in computing/IT?

Tags: word-request, terminology

I want a picture to appear simultaneously with the start of some applications. In this case, which verb should I use?

- > **Bind** the picture to the start of the application.
- > **Tie-in** the picture to the start of the application.

Are those verbs right?

If not, is there any synonyms for using in the context of technologies?

Comment: The proper term is: "Splash Screen." You are *setting* the image as the *Splash Screen*.

Answer (score 2):

These pictures have a specific name: **startup image**.

If you say

> Display startup image...

your average tech-savvy reader should immediately know to display the image at the start of the application.

Comment: Thank you, but I wasn't trying to use any terms. I've only used regular words to give an example of a sentence. It doesn't mean I'm asking help with technical words)
My question is about synonims to the words "bind" and "tie-in". If it helps, I can give another example:

"The option allows users to bind/tie-in the start of a playlist column to the end of recording".

Answer (score 0):

*affix* ____ to ____ 
  
1. To attach.

  
2. To subjoin, annex, or add at the close or end

  
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affix#Verb

*attach* ____ to ____ 
  
2. To fasten, to join to (literally and figuratively). 

  
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attach#Verb

*associate* ____ with ____ 
  
4. To connect or join together; combine. 

  
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/associate#Verb

*couple* ____ and / to ____ 
  
1. To join (two things) together, or (one thing) to (another).

  
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/couple#Verb